# Compare dynamic error message using Error.Is function

Tags: go, error-handling

I have a dynamic error message for example

```
metadata.name: invalid value "test-value"
```

"test-value" will be dynamic, and I need to do something if this error pattern appears

How to check the errors pattern with Error.Is function?

Comment: You can't, that's the opposite of what `errors.Is` is for. You likely want a custom error type and to use `errors.As`. You also definitely want to take a look at the [`errors` package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/errors), it's clear and concise, it only takes a minute to read through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your error has a dynamic message. I think you mean that you're defining a type that satisfies the `error` interface. (If you're using `fmt.Errorf` instead though, you *should* define a type for this use case).

```
type invalidValueError struct {
  value string
}

func (e *invalidValidError) Error() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("invalid value %q", e.value)
}
```

You can check whether any given error has this type using `errors.As`. This will match not only the error itself, but any errors it's wrapping.

```
if ive := (*invalidValueError)(nil); errors.As(err, &ive) {
  // got an *invalidValueError
}
```

Avoid matching the text of error messages if at all possible. They can change on different systems or in different locales, and they're generally not covered by compatibility promises.